# Python overloaded operator is not working in both "sides" of an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm implementing a `Fraction` class to work with fractions (although python have a library for this), well the problem is, I can use the `__add__` (+) operator between a fraction and an integer, but I can't use `__add__` between an integer and a fraction. When the expression's order changes, I get an error.

```
>>> a = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> a + 1
Fraction(numerator=3.0, denominator=2)
>>> 1 + a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Fraction'
>>>
```

Is there a way to make this expression `1 + Fraction(1, 2)` work? Perhaps a left `__add__` operator for the `Fraction` class?

Comment: [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement `radd` mirroring add.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Fraction(self.value+other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print((Fraction(1)+1).value)
    print((1+Fraction(1)).value)
```